# How to integrate mailGun SDK in windows 7?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to PHP, I want to integrate "Mailgun SDK", I got from this link https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php, but I don't know how to use this library because I am using windows 7, so please help me.

Comment: Are you using codeigniter since you added this tag?

Comment: Yes i am using codeigniter.

Comment: Start here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: thats right, but i am using mailgun sdk, so where will i put sdk code to codeigniter...